# Changing background image using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, background-image, setinterval

I'm trying to write a code to load asynchronously a background every "N" seconds.

OK! NOW EVERYTHING WORKS! But the first image start after 15 seconds. How to load at the end of page load?

```
(function(jQuery) {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/background.php',
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log("done Ok!");
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.onload = function() {
                jQuery('body').css({"background-image": data, "color": "red !important"});
                console.log("ok2!");
            };
            newImage.src = data;
        });
    }, 15000);
})(window.jQuery);
```

QUESTION SOLVED, BUT NOW I NEED how to load in background the background image.

Here the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766943/changing-background-image-using-jquery-and-ajax-but-async-and-in-background

Comment: **But something is wrong.** is not a very good problem description.

Comment: Try setting breakpoints within your console and check if .done() is executing. If not that will help lead you to what went wrong.

Comment: You don't actually appear to do anything with `newImage`, but if the `load` event isn't firing, then the logical conclusion is that it isn't loading. Did you check the console for network errors? Did you try adding an error handler to see if it gets fired?

Comment: Image load events are notoriously browser-specific.  Try attaching your event using jQuery: `$(newImage ).load(function() {...})`

Comment: Does http://www.example.com/background.php even return anything. I did not get any response back from it via ajax.

Comment: I edited my question, my friends.

Comment: Put your interval function as it's own named function (say `intervalFunction`) then do `window.setInterval(intervalFunction)`. And after that do `intervalFUnction()` to call it on page load.

Comment: Please stop changing the content of your question. Append updates to your question, don't replace it with a new question

Comment: @Populus, can you write code more clearly? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the looping function out of the `window.interval` call, as it's own function.

```
(function(jQuery) {
    function intervalFunc() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/background.php',
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log("done Ok!");
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.onload = function() {
                jQuery('body').css({"background-image": data, "color": "red !important"});
                console.log("ok2!");
            };
            newImage.src = data;
        });
    }

    window.setInterval(intervalFunc, 15000); // Start the interval timer
    intervalFunc();  // Run once first after page load
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok. Everything works. But for the second question you have an idea? You can edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in background.php

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and how that solves the problem *by editing your answer*.